# How to use Sed with spaces inside awk

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

My problem is : 
I have file1 :

```
 3119
 3359
 1359
 ...
```

and file2

```
 2222 abc
 3359 def              <---- this is a match
 4444 ghi
 ...
```

And I would like to modify each lines where indexes from file 1 are found in file 2 by prefixing the string. Result would be :

```
 2222 abc
 3359 PREFIXdef              <---- this is a match
 4444 ghi
 ...
```

I came up with this solution:

```
sed `cat file1.txt | awk '{print "-e s/"$1"/"$1"PREFIX./"}'`<<<"`cat file2.txt`"
```

Which give this result :

```
 2222 abc
 3359PREFIX def              <---- this is a match
 4444 ghi
 ...
```

How can I add a space before PREFIX and remove the one after ? I have an error 
(command not terminated)

Ideally I would add 2 apostrophes around the 's/xx / xx':

```
sed `cat file1.txt | awk '{print "-e 's/"$1" /"$1" PREFIX./'"}'`<<<"`cat file2.txt`"
```

But I can't escape the '' !!!

Comment: I highly recommend you read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins before attempting any more text manipulation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This awk command can handle that by reaching all 1st columns from first file into an associative array and then checking that against file2:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} $1 in a{$2 = "PREFIX" $2} 1' file1 file2

2222 abc
3359 PREFIXdef
4444 ghi
```

Comment: Incredibly simple !! :D

Comment: That's great, thanks!!
May I add this to take into account there was tab as separator in my files:
awk -v OFS='\t' ...

Comment: Right in that case `OFS='\t'` will be right way of getting correct output.